# Arc text in iphone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa, 3d, quartz-graphics

I want to bend the text that of UILabel  from corner. It just like appear as arc or as following link.

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/kfBzK4R4IlvyHfVywUNd1A?feat=directlink

please suggest me, from where i start. any documentation,link, sample code.

thanks

amit battan

Comment: Did you get it working the way you want?  If so, what'd you do?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be... create dynamically separate UILabel for each character with height and width of one character  in your view and put it's X Y co ordinates (position) in Arc type...
Did you get my point...?